# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid column name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am running into the exception below whenever I use an entity that I have defined.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid column name &apos;coordinator_sycs_coord_id&apos;.
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
```

I will post below the entities involved and the query that Hibernate is generating.  The context is two entities that have a many-to-many relationship in an association table. I find interesting that the query that Hibernate is generating is changing the column name even when I have it right in my annotations.  See below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sycs_coord")
public class SycsCoordinator {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "sycs_coord_id")
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<SycsCoordinatorClub> clubs;

    //Standard setters and getters below
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sycs_coord_clb")
@IdClass(SycsCoordinatorClubPk.class)
public class SycsCoordinatorClub {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "sycs_coord_id")
    Long sycs_coord_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "clb_id")
    String clb_id;

     @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "sycs_coord_id", referencedColumnName="sycs_coord_id")
    SycsCoordinator coordinator;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "clb_id", referencedColumnName = "Clb_id")
    Club club;

}
```

I am not including the classes `Club` and `SycsCoordinatorClubPk` for now because they seem irrelevant to the problem.  The query that Hibernate is generating some times is:

```
select
    clubs0_.club_Clb_Id as club4_0_3_,
    clubs0_.clb_id_fk as clb1_3_,
    clubs0_.sycs_coord_id as sycs2_3_,
    clubs0_.clb_id_fk as clb1_2_2_,
    clubs0_.sycs_coord_id as sycs2_2_2_,
    clubs0_.club_Clb_Id as club4_2_2_,
    clubs0_.coordinator_sycs_coord_id as coordina5_2_2_,
    clubs0_.lst_updt_dt as lst3_2_2_,
    clubs0_.sycs_coord_secur_grp_cd as sycs6_2_2_,
    sycscoordi1_.sycs_coord_id as sycs1_0_0_,
    sycscoordi2_.sycs_coord_secur_level_id as sycs4_3_1_ 
from
    sycs_coord_clb clubs0_ 
left outer join
    sycs_coord sycscoordi1_ 
        on clubs0_.coordinator_sycs_coord_id=sycscoordi1_.sycs_coord_id 
where
    clubs0_.club_Clb_Id=?
```

Notice that sometimes the column name `coordinator_sycs_coord_id` appears in the query, even when there is no such name in any of the annotations.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mis-using the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation, hence the strange results:

> It is used to join the primary table of an entity subclass in the
>   JOINED mapping strategy to the primary table of its superclass; it is
>   used within a SecondaryTable annotation to join a secondary table to a
>   primary table; and it may be used in a OneToOne mapping in which the
>   primary key of the referencing entity is used as a foreign key to the
>   referenced entity.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html

You should probably be using the @JoinColumn instead:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "sycs_coord_id", referencedColumnName = "sycs_coord_id")
```

Comment: I will test the answer an accept as soon as I am able to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked. I had to also add `updatable = false, insertable = false`. Thanks a lot.